# Turn laravel error output to span instead of div?

Tags: laravel

The following code:

```
{{ Form::error($errors->first('blah')) }}
```

Will produce:

```
<div class="help-block">My error.</div>
```

I want it to produce:

```
<span class="myError">My error.</span>
```

How do you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `Form::error()` in Laravel, so you might be using a Macro:

```
Form::macro('error', function()
{
    return '<div class="help-block">My error.</div>';
});
```

And you just have to change that code.